ORA-03113 error running Oracle container in Docker
I am on an Mac M1 machine. I am trying to spin up a docker container with the command
docker run -it -e ORACLE_PASSWORD=<pwd> gvenzl/oracle-free:23.3-slim-faststart

The image is pulled successfully, but the container fails
CONTAINER: starting up...
CONTAINER: first database startup, initializing...
CONTAINER: starting up Oracle Database...

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 23.0.0.0.0 - Production on 06-JUN-2024 14:16:33

Copyright (c) 1991, 2023, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /opt/oracle/product/23c/dbhomeFree/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 23.0.0.0.0 - Production
System parameter file is /opt/oracle/product/23c/dbhomeFree/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/6f5ae5f30019/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_FREE)))
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_FREE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 23.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                06-JUN-2024 14:16:34
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           FREE
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/23c/dbhomeFree/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/6f5ae5f30019/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_FREE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

The container just exits , it is not even available as a dangling container i.e. docker container ls does not show anything.
I have a lot of resources allocated to docker. Other commands - like spinning up a postgres container, works. Any help would be much appreciated.
I tried to spin up an Oracle container, and it exited with an error
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

The docker hub page from where the image originates suggests a different command for starting the container; have you tried that?

I tried
docker run -d -p 1521:1521 -e ORACLE_PASSWORD= gvenzl/oracle-free
I got the same error

Works fine for me; perhaps your problem is because you're running it on an M1 Mac

Then it's something else, but whatever it is, it's nothing to with Oracle.
